# Popup error for existing duplicate original is obscured

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, duplicate-questions, localization

If you try to add an existing duplicate original to the list while editing the list of duplicates you will see the error popup:

> [image: popup]

But it is actually hidden under the select original window:

> [image]

Also, the text

> The selected original is already listed!

can't be found in Transifex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The error was being attached relative to the body of the document, rather than the dialog.  There was also a bug when the server error dialog (add failed) would get hidden immediately after being shown.

The slightly revised text for both errors are [now in Transifex](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39983026#39983026).

Comment: Thanks, Brian. You are as always detailed and accurate!